# Shopping Cart Database Structure

Tags: mysql, shopping-cart

I have been studying the database structure for shopping carts and notice that when storing order details the  product information is repeated and stored again in the table. I was wondering what the reasoning behind this would be? Here is a small example of what i mean:

Product Table

```
product_id     name               desc         price
1            product 1    This is product 1    27.00
```

Order Table

```
order_id   customer id     order_total
1             3               34.99
```

Order Details Table

```
order_details_id    product_id       product name      price    qty
       1                1              product 1        27.00     1
```

So as you can see the product name and price are stored again in the order details table. Why is this? The only reason i can think of is because the product details may change after the order has been placed which may cause confusion. Is this correct?

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes this is the only reason

your product price get change frequently

so you can create one more table and store detail of product as shown below

Product update table

```
id product_id     name               desc         price
1     1            product 1    This is product 1    27.00
```

and order table will be

```
order_details_id    product_Update_id  qty
       1                1               1
```

Comment: I disagree with this answer. The third table is a Junction Table. Read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

Answer (score 0):

Its probably done for performance reasons, instead of having to do a JOIN, only a straight SELECT can be done to get order details.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your structure according

```
product_id     name               desc                 price
1              product 1          This is product 1    27.00

order_id  product_id  customer id   order_total
1         1           3             34.99

order_details_id   order_id  qty
1                  1         1
```

there is no need to take productname and its price in orderdetail just take order id 
and in order table add one field product_id

Comment: Are you suggesting to just add a product_id column in the order table? Surely this is not correct? What if there is more than one product in the order?